# Laravel artisan make command returning random files

Tags: php, laravel

Bit of a weird one

Today I went to run the following command: `php artisan make:model -m Document`, nothing crazy, do it all the time. For some reason however, the Model generated by this was an entirely random JSON string. This was the file output:

```
{
  "name": "@mdi/font",
  "version": "5.9.55",
  "description": "Dist for Material Design Webfont. This includes the Stock and Community icons in a single webfont collection.",
  "styl
```

I checked the migration file also generated, and it was providing something else (also random). SO I tried running a `composer update` and then reran the command, and got this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <page-title :heading="heading" :subheading="subheading" :icon="icon"></page-title>
    <tabs :tabs="tabs" :currentTab="currentTab" :wrapper-class="'body-tabs shadow-tabs'"
```

Appreciate any tips, I've been doing Laravel for 1.5-2 years and never seen this before..

Comment: That's very odd. It looks like it's grabbing random parts of your project and dropping them in the new files. Maybe try deleting your vendor folder and running `composer install` again?

Comment: Same story after running `rm -R vendor && composer install`

Comment: other commands as php artisan or php artisan route:list are working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by moving the `-m` parameter to the end of the command. Kind of odd, given that I've been doing it before the model name for the last year, but hey I'll take the win!